# R generate points with condition using runifpoint function

Tags: r, random, graphics, spatstat

I am trying to generate randomly distributed points in a rectangle.

To create 50 random points in a rectangle, I used

```
i=50
  pp<-runifpoint(i, win=owin(c(0,19.5),c(0,3.12))
```

If I were to add conditions on the coordinates before randomly generating points,

e.g.   0.24 <x<19.26  ,0.24<y<2.64  ,
then generate random points, what code can I imply?

The ultimate goal is to generate points in the rectangle except for the grey shaded area, in the below image

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question about the R package `spatstat`.

The argument `win` specifies the spatial region in which the points will be generated. In your example you have specified this region to be a rectangle. You just need to replace this rectangle by the region in which you want the points to be generated.

You can construct spatial regions (objects of class `owin`) in many ways. See `help(owin)`, or `help(spatstat)` for an overview.

In your example, you could build up the shape by forming the union of several rectangles. For example to make a simple cross shape, I could just write

```
require(spatstat)
A <- owin(c(-1,1), c(-4, 4))
B <- owin(c(-4,4), c(-1,1))
U <- union.owin(A, B)
plot(U)
```

Another way would be to specify the corners of the polygon shape and use `W <- owin(poly=p)` where `p = list(x, y)` contains the coordinates of the corners, listed in anticlockwise order without repetition. See `help(owin)`.

This is also covered in Section 3.5 of [the spatstat book](http://book.spatstat.org). You can download Chapter 3 for free.